Applying fundamental theorem of calculus where upper integration bound for F's associated integral is not equal to F's input
Normally, the FTC is stated like this:
Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$. For $x \in$ $[a, b]$, define $F(x)=\int_a^x f$. If $f$ is continuous at a point $x \in(a, b)$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x$, and $F^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$.
However, I'm looking at the following solution to a homework problem:
Question 6.2.26. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a connected open set, and let $\omega$ be a continuous differential 1-form on U. Suppose that $\int_\phi \omega=\int_\psi \omega$ whenever $\phi$ and $\psi$ begin and end at the same points. Show that there exists a $C^1$ function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\omega=d f$. (Hint: Consider how the fundamental theorem of calculus allows us to construct the antiderivative of a continuous function of a single variable as an integral.)
Let $p_0 \in U$ be fixed. Given any $p \in U$, we know that there exists some $\gamma_p:\left[a_p, b_p\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma_p$ is a smooth parametrized curve and $\gamma_p\left(a_p\right)=p_0$ and $\gamma_p\left(b_p\right)=p$. We then define
$$
f(p):=\int_{\gamma_p} \omega=\int_{a_p}^{b_p} \omega_{\gamma_p(t)}\left(\gamma_p^{\prime}(t)\right) d t
$$
which is well-defined by our assumption that the line integral of $\omega$ is path independent.
Our goal is now to show that $\omega=d f$. Given any point $x \in U$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we want to show that $\omega_x(v)=d f_x(v)$. We define a path $\kappa:(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \rightarrow U$ given by
$$
\kappa(t)=x+t v
$$
We have
$$
f(\kappa(t))=\int_{\gamma_{\kappa(t)}(s)} \omega=\int_{a_{\kappa(t)}}^{b_{\kappa(t)}} \omega_{\gamma_{\kappa(t)}(s)}\left(\gamma_{\kappa(t)}^{\prime}(s)\right) d s .
$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$
\frac{d}{d t}\left(f(\kappa(t))=\omega_{\kappa(t)}(v) .\right.
$$
Then for $x=\kappa(0)$, we check that $d f_x(v)=\omega_x(v)$ as desired. Since $\omega$ is continuous and differentiable, we can check that $f$ is a $C^1$ function.
My question is this -- how is this an application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? It seems like since f takes an input different from the upper integration bound, we cannot use the Fundamental Theorem; how is this resolved?

You need to be a bit more careful. Informally, $f(p) = \int_{p_0}^{p}\omega$, so $f(p + h) - f(p) = \int_{p}^{p + h}\omega$. Then if $p$ is sufficiently close to $p_0$, and $|h|$ is sufficiently small, you can choose the straight line path from $p$ to $p + h$ to evaluate the integral, and there you'll see that the fundamental theorem of calculus can be applied.

@Kakashi Thanks for the response. Could you please elaborate more on what you mean by your "informal" description of $f(p)$? Where does it come from and why is it only informal? And why does $p$ being sufficeintly close to $p_0$ and |$h$| being sufficiently small matter?

Actually it isn't informal, that was bad wording. You want to be able to choose the straight line path between $p$ and $p + h$. In order for this path to stay in $U$, you pick a ball $B$ around $p_0$ and make sure $p$ and $p + h$ are in $B$.

@Kakashi I'm confused by why we're looking at $p + h$ in the first place. In particular, why do we have a choice of $p+h$ that we can use to evaluate the integral, and which integral are you looking to evaluate? Beyond that, why are we looking to evaluate any integral, rather than just differentiate the specific integral we were interested in from before?

I'm using $f'(p) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(p + h) - f(p)}{h}$.

Let $f_i:U\to\Bbb R$ (for $i=1,\dots,n$) be the continuous functions such that $\omega=\sum_if_idx_i$. To prove that your candidate $f(p):=\int_{p_0}^p\omega$ is $C^1$ and $\omega=df$, it suffices to check that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=f_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Let us do it for instance for $i=1$. Let $e:=(1,0,\dots,0)$ and fix some  $p\in U$. For $|t|$ sufficiently small, the range $[p,p+te]$ of the line curve $\gamma(s):=p+se$ ($s\in[0,t]$) is inside $U$, and as $t\to0$,
$$\begin{align}\frac{f(p+te)-f(p)}t&=\frac1t\int_p^{p+te}\omega\\&=\frac1t\int_0^t\omega_{p+se}(e)ds\\&=\frac1t\int_0^tf_1(p+se)ds\\&\to f_1(p),\end{align}$$
by the FTC.
